# Remove cache after mutation in Apollo Client

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I want to reset apollo-client cache after a mutation.

```
const [loadDelete] = useMutation(REMOVE_PRODUCTS, {
  update(cache, result) {
    // here... how to remove cache?    

  },
})
```

How can I do this?

I tried...

```
cache.restore()
cache.resetStore()
cache.client.reset()
```

and none of aboves working.

---

I have page based query. If I click page 1,2,3. and the cache will

```
page1: [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]
page2: [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5]
page3: [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5]
```

In this situation, If I delete all page 1's elements I fetch latest data from server, and cache will updated like below:

```
page1: [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5]
page2: [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5]
page3: [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5]
```

And this time, If I hit `page2` it should show `[c1, c2, c3, c4, c5]` but it show `[b1, b2, b3, b4, b5]` because cache still exist.

That's because why I need this.

Answer (score 0):

I remove store like below.

```
const [loadDelete, { client }] = useMutation(REMOVE_PRODUCTS, {
  update(cache, result) {
    client.resetStore().then(() => { 
       // bla bla
    })
  },
})
```